# Foreach strange behavior

Tags: php

```
<html>
<body>

<select id="cod">
<?php
foreach ( range(-2, 2,0.25) as $cod ) {
echo '<option value=';
if($cod >= 0){
    echo '+';
}
echo number_format($cod, 2, '.', '');
if($cod == 0){
    echo ' selected="selected"';
}
echo ' style="background-color: #7dbb4d;>';
if($cod >= 0){
    echo '+';
}
echo number_format($cod, 2, '.', '');
echo '</option>';
}

echo '<br/>';
echo 'toto';
?>
</select>   
<?php echo 'echo something else....'; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Why 'echo something else....' doesn't display at the end of my code?
Sorry i'm pretty new to Php.

My est page is here : http://www.willbegood.com/test/debug.php

Comment: view source its there, its just your html is borked

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
echo ' style="background-color: #7dbb4d;>';
```

try:

```
echo ' style="background-color: #7dbb4d;">';
```

Comment: Always try to add few words of explanation when you post answer. Don't post only code.

Answer (score 0):

It is displaying but browser don't know how to show it. That's because you've got typo in your `HTML`

```
echo ' style="background-color: #7dbb4d;>';
```

It's missing closing `"` in `style` parameter.

```
echo ' style="background-color: #7dbb4d;>"';
```